# MongoDB collection error with type inheritance (FileFormatException)

Tags: c#, mongodb, inheritance

This is my first few days with Mongo (and NoSQL in general), so I may be trying something that is only possible in my head.

**Setup:**

DB: MongoDB 2.2.1

Interface: latest 10gen c# driver from nuget

I've got a general class like this

```
public class User { public string userName {get;set;} }
```

and then an application specific implementation like this

```
public class App1User : User { public int appSpecificProperty { get;set; } }
```

**Issue:**

In my application I can load a record that was saved as type User as either User or App1User.  Unfortunately once I save a record using the App1User type, I can no longer load it as a User (FileFormatException: Element 'appSpecificProperty' does not match any field or property of class User).

I load items like this:

```
var collection = mongDB.GetCollection<User>("users");
var query = new QueryDocument("username" : userName);
var user = collection.Find(query).SingleOrDefault(); // error here if record was type App1User
```

This is a problem as I want to use a user authentication library across multiple projects and then just extend the user object to add application specific settings.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that you need to mark your Parent class with this attribute

```
[BsonDiscriminator("baseuser", RootClass = true)]
```

Unfortunately this will only fix new records, I haven't figured out how to apply this fix to existing records that cannot load.

Comment: if you know what to update in the document, it should be possible to run an update query from mongo [interactive shell](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/mongo+-+The+Interactive+Shell) to all your problematic records.

Comment: i have the same thing, and i set [BsonDiscriminator] for all classes, and also i set root on roots..., yet still i tired something like this and i got error: "'FirstName' does not match any field or property of class RealEstate.Models.Owner.'" in `IEnumerable<T> all = _db.GetCollection<T>(_tableName).FindAll();
            var list = all.ToList();
            return list;` i start building my project based on something i never finished long ago, i was created these model in a inheritence hierarchy form in NHibernate, but now i'm not sure if mongo support, or how should i call/store them

Comment: let me add, the owner him self is not useful, and i store a model of type person, or agency which are inherited from Owner.